# Converting a line of words from lower case to upper case

Tags: java, string

I would like to convert a line of words, including punctuation and spaces, from lower case to upper case. My method to deal with the question is to firstly store the sentence in String form, then apply the "toUpperCase" Java class to it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = in.next();
    String upper = input.toUpperCase();

    System.out.println(upper);

}
```

But it reads a sentence with spaces or punctuation in the middle, something would come out like this:

```
you are so smart!
YOU
```

How to solve this problem? Can anyone give me some advice? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
 String input = in.next();
```

In to

```
 String input = in.nextLine(); // you need to take entire line
```

Now

```
 Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
 String input = in.nextLine();
 String upper = input.toUpperCase();

 System.out.println(upper);
```

Out out:

```
 YOU ARE SO SMART
```

More info: Read [next()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) and [nextLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29)

Answer (score 2):

`in.read()` will return you the next token (as per [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()), *a complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the delimiter pattern*, , which by defaul matches a whitespace), not the next line.

Change

```
String input = in.next();
```

to

```
String input = in.nextLine();
```

If you still want to stick to the "`in.next()` approach" and get the entire line, you can change the delimiter pattern. Like this:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\n");
```

In this case, a *token* will be everthing that ends with a line-breaking character (`\n`) and `in.next()` will return you the entire line.

Answer (score 1):

```
 String input = in.next();
```

When you store input by using .next(), whenever the scanner encounters a whitespace it stops reading for input. Whereas if you use

```
 String input = in.nextLine();
```

the scanner will input the complete line entered by the user. 
In simple terms,
next() - to input a word
nextLine() - to input a sentense